# Hosting multiple laravel apps on a server

Tags: php, laravel-5, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two applications and a server, specifically windows server 2012 and I use IIS to host my application. The first application is working fine and I access it through it's ip address (ex. 192.168.0.253) and pointed to netpub/laravel/public the problem is how do I access the second application using the same IP address, any one got any suggestions?

Comment: You don't use IP addresses, use virtual hosts instead!

Comment: And why IIS? you'll need some tools to tweak it to work faster with PHP, tools like wincache

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you.

Comment: What platform do you suggest? Should I stick to xampp?

Comment: I just realized I've been using virtual host although I think it only works on local PC. What if I wanted to access the application on a different PC?

Comment: XAMPP may be used as a development environment, but for production, it would be better if you could install Nginx, MySQL and PHP version you need yourself

Comment: I'll definitely try that. Thank you. But how would nginx solve my problem?

Comment: I didn't say it will solve your problem, you are trying to work with PHP, so I'm suggesting the tools that goes with, IIS was not designed for hosting PHP application !

Comment: IIS is a legitimate platform to run PHP on maybe it's not the best but migrating shouldn't be hard anyway. Laravel even comes with a `web.config` file. However you need to set up a virtual host.

Comment: And to be honest, I still don't get your second question, you were complaining about not being able to access multiple websites on the same server, virtualhosts will help you with that

Comment: Is nginx cross-platform? I mean I'm hosting my applications on windows server 2012

Comment: Okay, so I need to setup virtual host. I still need to read a lot about virtual host as I dont understand it fully.

Comment: @apokryfos it's like you are saying that you can use notepad for writing C programs, I mean sure you can, but it was not made for that purpose, and believe me I worked with IIS server on a big project with PHP, it's a pain in the ass to make it perform better

Comment: That being said, either on IIS, nginx or Apache you will need to setup virtual hosts and depending on your webserver the procedure will be different. The idea is to tell your webserver that whenever it receives a request to serve `site1.example.com` it should serve it from directory X and whenever it receives a request to serve `site2.example.com` it should serve it from directory Y. You need to refer to your webserver instructions (or existing SO questions) to find out how to do that.

Comment: Yes, regardless of whatever server. there's one thing I dont understand. Whenever I try accessing mysite.com from pc1 to server it doesn't work.

Comment: If you don't own the DNS for `mysite.com` then you can setup your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file to have 127.0.0.1 (or whatever IP you need) point to `mysite.com`

Comment: Okay so I need DNS to have a host name. I can't manually edit each hosts file of each client pc's to have them to connect the system right? i think this is resolved though not solved since I am wrong on my part.

Comment: If you want other people to access multiple pages hosted on a single machine you will need to buy a domain DNS entry , add subdomains, and have each subdomain point to your IP. That's the proper way to do it. However if you don't want to pay for a DNS then you can presumably host both pages under different subfolders of your public root and access them via e.g. `http://<ipaddress>/site1/public` and `.../site2/public` but that just looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since one IP address can be assigned to one computer at a time,

I created a startup script on my linux machine that starts each laravel application on a different port over the network. For example

Script 1 for 1st app:

```
php <PATH_TO_LARAVEL_PROJECT>/artisan serve --host=<IP_ADDRESS> --port=8000
```

Script 2 for 2nd app:

```
php <PATH_TO_LARAVEL_PROJECT>/artisan serve --host=<IP_ADDRESS> --port=8001
```

.

.

.

Script n for n app:

```
php <PATH_TO_LARAVEL_PROJECT>/artisan serve --host=<IP_ADDRESS> --port=nnnn
```

You can do this for multiple projects over same IP address.